# как анимировать текстовое значение от 100 до 20

Tags: javascript, jquery

как анимировать значение в `<span>100</span>` от 100 до 20

Comment: `setInterval/setTimeout` + read/write значения

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var block = $('span'),
  start = parseInt(block.text()), // парсим число
  stop = 20, // окончание анимации
  step = 1; // шаг пересчета
var timeout = setInterval(function() {
  if (start > stop) {
    start = start - step;
    block.text(start);
  } else {
    clearInterval(timeout); // очищаем интерввал
  }
}, 30); // интервал между пересчетами
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>100</span>
```

Comment: Надо бы наверное в конце очистить интервал, чтоб не продолжал фигачить вхолостую

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо, дополнил ответ

Answer (score 3):

```js
setTimeout(function dec() {
  if (--document.querySelector('span').textContent - 20) {
    setTimeout(dec, 300)
  }
}, 300)
```

```html
<span>100</span>
```